# Is it possible to run multiple binaries from a single module via npx?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

(Note: I'm using the [cowsay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cowsay) module here to illustrate my point)

Without installing a module on my computer I can run it directly via npx with:

```
npx cowsay Hello!
```

If I have multiple binaries specified in `package.json`.

```
"bin": {
    "cowsay": "./cli.js",
    "cowthink": "./cli.js"
},
```

I'd also like to do

```
npx cowthink Hello!
```

But this fails. Is this because npx runs the module named `cowsay` and just runs the first command it finds in the `"bin"` field in `package.json`?

Is there a way to run `cowthink` directly from `npx`?

Answer (score 27):

As [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx#description) states,

> Unless a --package option is specified, npx will try to guess the name of the binary to invoke depending on the specifier provided

If binary and package names don't match, this is what [`--package` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx#description) is for:

```
npx -p cowsay cowthink Hello!
```