# distribute two binaries to be executed with npx

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npx

Got a package with the following `package.json` file (part of it)

```
{
  "name": "test-package",
  "bin": {
    "hello": "./hello.js",
    "world": "./world.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
```

where the files contain the executable path and can be run with `node path/to/js` as well.

Now, i want a user to be able to run `npx test-package hello` or `npx test-package world`

So far, the only way I could make it run is to use `"bin":"./hello.js"`

I have checked the [option `--package` or `-p` and fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571669/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-binaries-from-a-single-module-via-npx), so I presume this is not possible, but want to be sure and maybe be explained why.